# How much does the Enterprise increase/vary in size between models?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-enterprise, uss-enterprise

In the show Enterprise, it's mentioned the ship has a complement of about 80 and you also see some of the MACOs sharing quarters in season 3 (although they are not part of the normal crew so it's not clear if this is the norm).

In TNG I *think* I recall that the ship has about 400 crew (and TOS somewhere in between) and family on board. Yet the ships look pretty similar so I wondered do the ships really get much larger or is it just one of those details which don't tie up across the Star Trek universe - like how the Enterprise ship looks far more like the TNG one than the TOS one even though it's more primitive.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is a picture of the Enterprises lined up together; the last one is the new version of the Enterprise from the post-2009 movies:

[image: Comparison of _Enterprise_ sizes]

The first is the [NX-class Enterprise from the Enterprise series](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Enterprise_%28NX-01%29); its crew complement appears to be 83.

The second is the [original Constitution-class Enterprise from TOS](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701%29); its crew complement is 205 in the 2250s, then 450 in the 2260s.

The third is the [Constitution-class refit Enterprise from TOS movies](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701)#Refits_and_further_service) as well as the identical [rebuilt Enterprise](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-A%29) after the original was destroyed. It looks like this version from the movies carried closer to the 450 complement.

The fourth is an [Excelsior-class refit](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-B%29) used in Generations.

The fifth is an [Ambassador-class starship](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-C)) which appeared in the TNG episode "Yesterdays Enterprise".

The sixth, the [Enterprise-D](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-D)), is a Galaxy-class starship from the TNG TV series and also featured (and destroyed) in the movie Generations. Crew approximately 1014, plus 200 visiting, 15,000 total emergency rooming.

The seventh, the [Enterprise-E](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-E)), is a Sovereign-class from the TNG movies from First Contact onwards; crew approximately 750-850, 4000 total emergency rooming.

The eighth as I said is the new, larger [re-imagined Constitution-class Enterprise](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28alternate_reality%29) from the JJ Abrams alternate universe "Star Trek" and "Into Darkness" (the increased size is due to encountering Nero's huge ship I believe).

Comment: Ah, 400 was TOS - wow, 1000+ in TNG is huge :)

Comment: TOS has a few different specs, it appears originally in the show it was set to 205, and then i believe it went through a retro fit for the first couple of movies in which it held about 450-500, and then the A held about 500-600, there are alot of different numbers for the original ships.

Comment: Some arguments that the 2009 Enterprise makes more sense visually as a smaller ship (and was apparently originally designed as such according to a quote from ILM Art Director Alex Jaeger), based on details like window sizes, can be found [here](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/articles/new_enterprise_comment.htm).

Comment: @Hypnosifl i saw somethings about that as well that the original enterprise was to small for the shuttle craft to enter.

Comment: For completeness' sake it should be noted that for an increase in length (which can be compared well in the above graphic) by factor *n*, volume will increase by a factor of *n³*. Even though the ships are (thankfully!) not just gradually scaled up version of the exact same shape, that is why the Enterprise-D appears to be barely 3 times as long as the NX-01 and yet it has a crew complement of more than 1000 people as opposed to the NX-01's 80 (*and* the Enterprise-D feels much emptier nonetheless).

Comment: Also, for further precision in this excellent answer: "Third i believe in the enterprise from TOS movies" - yes, or actually, the *two* Enterprises (the first of which was hte same, refurbished, ship as the one above). And "Forth and Fifth i believe are the enterprises between TOS and TNG (however the 4th may also be the enterprise that Kirk was on and when missing in generations)" - yes, they are the Enterprises between TOS and TNG *and* at the same time, the Enterprise-B is the one that Kirk went missing on.

Comment: Great answer. Would be even better if you could add the class designations for each. I know Galaxy and Sovereign, but not the others.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I went ahead and added all the classes and links to their Memory Alpha pages.  Memory Alpha has [a list of all ships named Enterprise mentioned in Star Trek](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28disambiguation%29).

Comment: @Schwern: The first Enterprise is (also on that page) said to belong to the "NX-class".

Comment: @Himarm TOS episodes refer to a 400+ crew size, as do the TOS-era Technical Manual books. 430 or so IIRC.

Comment: Note also that the primary hull on the Connie (pre- and post-refit) was circular, while on the Galaxy it was much more elliptical.  IIRC, the original Connie was supposed to be around the same size as a Nimitz-class aircraft carrier (which typically has a complement of over 4000 (yes, four *thousand*) officers and crew).

Comment: I had no idea the Abrams-verse NCC-1701 was so bloody huge!

Comment: Yeah, it's clear in the hanger deck scenes that the ship is much bigger. The Enterprise from TOS could only carry about 4 or 5 shuttlecraft at a given time.  The JJ Enterprise carried easily 4 or 5 times that many, maybe more.

Comment: @JohnBode - you're right about the TOS ship's size, but it held far less crew because of the interior space arrangement. A modern carrier is fairly "squished" inside, whereas the starship wasn't.

Comment: @Omegacron: Oh, yeah, starship crews don't hot-bunk, and they don't cram racks into any random wasted space.  I was just marveling at how many people the Navy can manage to cram into one ship.  Carriers are big, but not *that* big.

Comment: Yep - serving on a modern carrier or sub is NOT for the claustrophobic.

Answer (score 3):

While the ships share a similar appearance, with a saucer and two warp nacelles, they scale up in size as they were developed. The new size is reflected in the number of crew each ship supported.

- Enterprise (NX-01), crew of [82](http://www.ussenterprise.co.uk/enterprise/entnx/)
- Enterprise (NCC-1701), living quarters for  [200-400](http://www.ussenterprise.co.uk/enterprise/ent/)
- Enterprise-D (Galaxy class), living quarters for [1014](http://www.ussenterprise.co.uk/enterprise/entd/entdtech.htm)
- Enterprise-E (Sovereign class), living quarters for [750](http://www.ussenterprise.co.uk/enterprise/ente/entetech.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In the original series we only see quarters for bridge officers, other senior officers, and a few junior officers. All seemed to be some reconfigured versions of Captain Kirk's three-room(one assumes there was a private bathroom) suite. One never sees enlisted crew quarters, such as the stacked bunks as was seen in the movie ST:The Undiscovered Country. Of course, in some material I've read, it was asserted that Starfleey was an all officer service. An argument my Father, a retired USAF Chief Master Sergeant, never bought into. In ST:TNG we see a cabin door opened from a corridor showing a bed and little else. It was also acknowledge that there were enlisted, and NCO crew personal, "...I'm not an officer, I work for a living" as Chief O'Brine so assertively stated. 
Templerman aka William York.

Comment: Which is odd in itself since we know they are 'enlightened' enough not to have money ;)

Comment: Referencing Mr. Boy's comment: Kirk often made reference to "Scotty and others earning their pay". I suspect these were archetypal references, idealizing someone performing above and beyond what is expected. It seems that several times throughout the franchise we have heard characters talk about burning through their transporter credits et.al. If you have a technological base like they have, power equals material, equals comforts, and other needs. All that's left is dividing it up in an equitable fashion. Even so, given a choice between their world and ours, I would choose theirs hands down.

Answer (score -1):

For those that may not know, the first Enterprise concept was a wood model with a spherical main section.  The nacelles were pointed downward.  It may have been Gene -- I don't know -- that said, "flip it over."  Then it became figure B.  He said, "That's it."  I don't how the transition from sphere to saucer occurred.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is about ship size, not designs.