# Crew quarters on the Enterprise in Star Trek (2009) and Into Darkness

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, uss-enterprise, star-trek-reboot

Something that bothers me is that, in the two alternate timeline Star Trek films, we do not see crew quarters — not even once.

**Were sets for crew quarters built at any point?  If not, does concept art exist?**

I'm especially interested to know if the quarters were intended to be on the cozy side, as in *TOS*, or if they were more spacious.  As we know, the Enterprise NCC-1701 in the new timeline is larger even than the Galaxy class NCC-1701-D, purportedly as a reaction to the size of Nero's ship*.   The top-rated response to the question

[How much does the Enterprise increase/vary in size between models?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78994/)

features a nice graphic exhibiting the size differentials. I wonder how this size gain impacts the design of interior spaces — in particular the crew cabins.

*<sub>I take any explanations of oddities in the new timeline with a grain of salt.</sub>

Comment: The crew can't get any sleep anyway from all the lens flares.

Comment: I don't think they had quarters. When Carol Marcus had to change her clothes, she didn't go to her quarters, she just had Kirk turn around and "not look." In my experience, women don't randomly strip down in public when they have doors they can lock.

Comment: @geewhiz : more evidence that quarters do not exist in the Abrams-verse!

Comment: @Praxis : They need the extra space on the ship to store all that lens flare they're carting around the galaxy. It's basically lens flare storage and naked crewmen wrapped around a warp core

Comment: @geewhiz : ...a warp core in the middle of an engineering section that looks like the Duff beer factory.

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Constitution_class_(alternate_reality) - LOts of relevant info here. You can find all sorts of (conflicting) schematics on the DVDs and video games.

Comment: @Richard : Thanks.  Please consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: @Praxis - I don't have access to the Bluray disc or the games mentioned.

Comment: @Praxis In 2009 star trek, wasn't engineering filmed in a budweiser factory, and for Into Darkness the warp core was filmed around a fusion laser ignition thingie?

Comment: @CBredlow : I suspect you are correct on both counts.  Someone should have shown Orci and Kurtzman a screenshot of a warp core the original films or *TNG*, before they started writing.

Comment: During Not!Kirk's monologue at the beginning of ID ("Our adventures have become...*episodic*") we see a corridor in a crew section, and the spacing between doors suggests something relatively roomy (on the order of a nice hotel room).  But that's just a guess based on that one tracking shot.  TBH, the JJ-Prise is just a hot mess top to bottom - the scale and interior layout just don't make sense.

Comment: @JohnBode : Agreed.  Also, in my opinion, it's just not a nice ship.  It looks okay on the outside, but the bridge design is obnoxious, the hallways have no consistency, and engineering looks disgusting. Something that *TNG* introduced was consistency of design.  You know that a location is Starfleet right away, from the consistent colours, doors, halls, and LCARS displays.  In JJ-world, I'm not even sure sometimes if I'm on the same ship or not, let alone whether it's Starfleet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no crew quarter sets were constructed for either Star Trek or Into Darkness, nor was any concept art drawn.

The best that we can do is from the ongoing [Star Trek IDW comics](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_%28IDW_ongoing%29), stated to be part of the [official Star Trek canon](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2012/07/straight-from-roberto-orci-current-trek-comics-are-canon) by Trek writer Robert Orci.

We see Spock's Quarters in [#006](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Operation:_Annihilate!_Part_2) and [#018](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Voice_of_a_Falling_Star)

[image]

[image]

And Hendorff (AKA Cupcake)'s quarters in [#013](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Redshirt%27s_Tale). Note that he appears to have a bunk bed, suggesting that lower ranks are quartered together:

[image]

Comment: Ah, the magical sheet that stays up without straps, and covers women completely but men only to the waist. Popular in movies, too.

Comment: @JohnP - http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ModestyBedsheet