# Where do crew members of Enterprise NCC-1701 have their meals?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-reboot

In *Star Trek: Enterprise*, they called it the "mess hall". Have we seen a similar room on the *Enterprise* in the Abramsverse movies?

Comment: Let me get this right.  Are you asking what Abrams' NCC1701 calls the place that Enterprise called the Mess Hall?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question to make it more clear. You're welcome to roll my edit back if you don't like it, or you can make further edits to clarify your question

Comment: Truly it should be referred to as the Mess Deck. A Mess Hall is a military dining facility on *land*.

Comment: I don't recall anything like a mess hall in the Next Generation series. It looked like everyone ate in their quarters. While you sometimes see people dining in 10-Forward, it looks like kind of a date-night thing rather than everyday dining.

Comment: We don't even see quarters in the reboot films, not once: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80674/crew-quarters-on-the-enterprise-in-star-trek-2009-and-into-darkness?rq=1

Comment: @Monty129 And a *mess deck* is a military dining facility on a *seagoing vessel*. ;) Plus, Starfleet is only partially military.

Answer (score 7):

## No.

A number of common starship facilities that would be on the Enteprise are not actually seen in the Abramsverse films.

In neither *Star Trek* (2009) nor *Star Trek Into Darkness* (2013) do we see a mess hall, a ship's galley, an officer's lounge, or any crew quarters.

Between all the yelling and running around in the reboot films, there doesn't seem to be any time for eating or sleeping.

Apparently, the DVD extras for *Star Trek* (2009) have undeveloped concept art for quarters.  They may also have concept art for other facilities such as the mess, but I cannot attest to this.

See also Richard's answer to [Crew quarters on the Enterprise in Star Trek (2009) and Into Darkness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80674/).

Comment: +1 for "Between all the yelling and running around in the reboot films, there doesn't seem to be any time for eating or sleeping."