# What is the canonicity of the appearance of USS Enterprise NCC-1701-B?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, uss-enterprise

This question arises from the answer to [In which ways did scanning Nero's ship enhance/change Starfleet technology?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97593/3823)

which shows this image

[image]

I believe all the USS Enterprises appeared on-screen except NCC 1701-B.

What is the origin of this image and what is its canonicity?

To those people who are claiming this is duplicate:  this has nothing to do with the other question.   This is a question about this specific image and Enterprise-B.   The other question just asks how many Enterprises there were.   The fact the answer to a question may happen to answer another question doesn't make the questions duplicate.   Furthermore,  the other question doesn't ask about the image.

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-B)

Comment: Looking for canon in Star Trek is a fool's game. The franchise has never even aimed for visual consistency, and always been openly revisionist on plot.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive given that there are both images from the film and concept artworks to refer to. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [NCC-1701-B](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-B)) appears on screen (briefly) at the start of [Star Trek: Generations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GbKUVK_Ct0) which means that its canonicity is **total**.

[image]

That being said, the artwork pictured in your question appears to be largely based on John Eaves' [original concept art](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/0/03/USS_Enterprise_NCC-1701-B_design_sketches_by_John_Eaves.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110419123254&path-prefix=en) for the ship, itself based on [earlier concept art pictures](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/6/63/Excelsior_Class_original_concept_designs_by_Nilo_Rodis.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/434?cb=20110415202711&path-prefix=en)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great answer, +1. Just to add one point: Eaves' concept art is not entirely original.  The Enterprise-B is Excelsior Class and Eaves' artwork mostly consists of minor modifications to the original Excelsior design (first appearing in *The Search for Spock*) due to David Carson and Nilo Rodis-Jamero --- see [Excelsior class model](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Excelsior_class_model).

Comment: @Praxis - Noted and edited.

Comment: Good answer, but can you elaborate on what features of the diagram lead you to think it was based on the concept art rather than the onscreen version shown in a number of shots in *Generations*? Also, note that the idea of the Enterprise-B as an Excelsior Class ship seems to have originated with the *Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual*, p. 4. It might also be worth comparing the diagram above to the one that appears in the *Star Trek Encyclopedia*, though I don't have it handy at the moment.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I was thinking that the extension of the nacelles from the rear portion of the fuselage was far more similar to the concept art than the real ship.

Comment: [This page](http://www.mutara.net/Christies/Lakota.html) has some shots of the original filming model, the model does seem to have those extensions on the nacelles as seen in [this shot](http://www.mutara.net/Christies/detail%20models/Lakota/IMG_1726.JPG), though they might be a bit smaller proportionally (they definitely seem a bit smaller in [this schematic](http://books.google.com/books?id=cbYf2l7gczUC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT646) from the *Star Trek Encyclopedia*). By "big red balls" do you mean the ones on the Enterprise-C or do you mean something on the Enterprise-B?

Comment: I don't see any red balls on the front of the nacelles--maybe you're getting mixed up by the labeling? The name label is the text underneath each ship, not above it, so the one with the giant red ball at the front of the nacelle is the Enterprise-C (compare with images [here](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-C))).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Oops. Duh. This is what happens when you stare at a zoomed in image for too long :-)

Comment: That concept art is gorgeous.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Everything that man draws is a joy to behold.

Answer (score 26):

Some further evidence about the state of canon of the *Enterprise-B*, it is actually shown well before *Generations* in model form in the **Observation lounge of the *Enterprise-D***:

[image: Models of all ships named Enterprise on the Enterprise-D]

Comment: @KyleKanos hand drawn, not anti-aliased, red circles.  Booya.

Comment: @KyleKanos gotta love freehand circles 

Comment: Damn. My answer only has a picture of the ship itself and no freehand circles. Damn!

Answer (score 17):

The USS Enterprise B was indeed shown onscreen, its maiden flight was the opening few scenes of [Star Trek Generations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations)

[image]