# What reality has more advanced technology?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-reboot

Which reality has more advanced technology in the Star Trek universe, prime or alternate? It seems that the prime universe has more advanced technology in terms of sensors etc, but alternate pushes development of weapons etc, and has leaps in technology such as transwarp beaming.

Comment: At which point in history?

Comment: Well kick era, since that when the timeline split.

Comment: The timelines split before Kirk was born.

Comment: Fair enough, just before, during his birth

Comment: The Enterprise depicted in the new alternate timeline is dramatically more powerful and technologically advanced than the Enterprise seen in TOS.

Comment: @Valorum why is this?

Comment: Improved special effects.  :-)

Comment: Bigger budget. HD cameras.

Comment: @Valorum I was thinking more in universe. For example salvage from the Romulan ship

Comment: I'm tempted to close as a dupe of this; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97593/in-which-ways-did-scanning-neros-ship-enhance-change-starfleet-technology

Comment: @Valorum fair enough, however some of the technology is very mechanical conspired to the prime universe eg: warp core, water systems

Comment: @Valorum and the alternate enterprise is a lot bigger :/

Comment: @CBredlow - I reckon that's down to the bigger budget, both in and out of universe.

Comment: @Pioneer something I noticed that was different on the kelvin was that the ship had almost ball-turret like phaser emitters that could be aimed as anti-missile defenses.

Comment: "It seems that the prime universe has more advanced technology in terms of sensors etc" -- It might help if you elaborated on this comment, I can't think of any ways in which TOS Trek had more advanced sensors than the Kelvin Timeline, and what else is included in your "etc"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Reboot universe

The universe seen in the Reboot timeline of Star Trek has more advanced technology than the same time period in the Prime timeline.  This is due to Starfleet's exposure to the Narada, the Romulan vessel from the late 24th Century whose incursion into the 23rd Century had created the divergence between the two timelines.

From director J.J. Abrams himself:

> The idea of the story is that at the beginning of the film something happens that changes the course of history. They cross paths with this futuristic ship, and it changes everything that would've been the classic series Trek fans are familiar with... ***One could argue that, based on the readings they got from the [Romulan] ship that showed up, it inspired ideas and technology that wouldn't have advanced otherwise... On the one hand, you could answer the question by saying that history got a boost, an adjustment, from this moment at the beginning of the film...***

([Source](http://www.mtv.com/news/1611878/jj-abrams-responds-to-star-trek-fans-theories/))

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the alternate (JJ) universe is more technologically advanced. Think about how long Admiral Marcus (Peter Weller) was working with Kahn (Benedict Cumberbatch) while he was attempting to start that war with the Klingons. We don't know how long that partnership was going before "Into Darkness". At the very least, long enough to build the USS Vengeance (dreadnaught class). That ship was considerably more advanced than Kirk's Enterprise in the same universe, much less the prime universe Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

In an online post, [Bob Orci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberto_Orci#Star_Trek_reboot), the writer of the first two Star Trek (reboot) films not only confirmed that the tech was indeed more advanced but he also confirmed *why*.

> **Q.** *I'll take any fanboy throwaway reference as to why the tech in this
> timeline is so advanced compared to the original TOS timeline, and how
> Nero blowing up the Kelvin changed that. Any explanation that works
> within the confines of Nero traveling back in time would do. Thanks a
> lot.*
>
> **Orci:** *Certainly **one would expect that the fleeing shuttles carrying
> survivors would also carry whatever telemetry was recorded by the
> Kelvin in its final moments** ( like an airplanes BLACK BOX). **Imagine
> the wealth of information that Starfleet was exposed to from scans of
> the Narada.***
>
> <sub><sup>[AICN DEDICATED TALKBACK: STAR TREK Lives!!](http://www.aintitcool.com/node/41001)</sup></sub>

Comment: Watched Beyond today, I see what's you mean. I like JJ's take on more mechanical systems, which we don't see in the prime universe. Having engineering being all cosy, and pressing a few buttons to reconfigure something isn't very realistic